# Chrome's "Replay XHR" feature removed?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, post, xmlhttprequest

I've been using Chrome's "Replay XHR" feature quite a lot for debugging purposes, but it seems to be gone all of a sudden? It used to be there about a week ago.

What could be the cause of this? My chrome is on version `Version 54.0.2840.100 (64-bit)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah - I'm quite sure it didn't disappear - but this specific XHR request also uploads a file. This is why the replay function is unavailable.

Comment: can you explain more, which kind of xhr can not be replayed ? and I want to know where can I find these change log about this feature. thanks

Comment: In my case the request uploaded a file - and thats why i can't replay it.

Comment: I can't find it, and I am not using file upload

Comment: `Replay XHR` is gone for me as well, and my XHR is definitely not uploading a file. There must be something else.

Comment: Something, something `fetch` API, c.f. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=597400