# My dev tools are missing the "replay xhr" option

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm currently using verison 72.0.3626.119 on a Debian Strecht. I've noticed that since a couple of days (perhaps one or two weeks)
I'm missing the *Replay XHR* menu entry you get when you do a right click on an XHR request in the network
window as [described here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#replay-xhr).

I've been also searching google for this with mixed results, I've found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220185/chromes-replay-xhr-feature-removed) from 2016 where
the OP seems to have a similar issue but since my xhr request are not uploading files, this does not apply to me either.
In the devtool forums I've found nothing that could help.

So the question is, is this function also gone for everybody else? Or is it just me? I've gone through the devtools
settings but I didn't find any option that would help me with this.

Comment: I don't see it as well (Mac OS),  v72.0.3626.121

Comment: Gone for me as well.

Answer (score 52):

The replay XHR still there if you are using the xhr api via axios or something similar, however, if your app is using the new api fetch, you need to use a different approach.

Since Chrome 67, it was introduced a new feature called [copy as fetch](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/04/devtools#fetch).

In that case, you can copy as fetch and paste on your console.

So, if you'd like to replay your fetch requests, just paste on your console, then press <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd> to replay your XHR.

The best part of that on the new feature is that you are able to edit your request, before replay.

[image]

Comment: I've been using *copy as cURL* whenever the menu does not appear. The strange thing is that sometimes *replay xhr* does appear. I just don't know how to reproduce it.

Comment: Something related to `fetch` API, c.f. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=597400

Comment: This causes CORS issues for me locally

Comment: Are you trying to fetch from the same window. You copied? Because copy as fetch should bring the correct origin settings

Comment: You can replay a POST but not a GET request

Comment: I am not sure what you mean @paul-warelis, but you can definitely copy as fetch to use for any method, POST, GET, PUT, etc... even the screenshot shows a GET method

Comment: The option to replay the request from the context menu on the network tab depends on the request method. A POST is replayable but a GET is not.

Comment: "The best part of that on the new feature" ... sorry, but I fail to see any benefits here.

What used to be two clicks, is now two clicks, then switching to console, paste, enter, switching back to network tab \:

Sill upvoted of course, since none of that is your fault :)